# Firebase / Node Reading

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from the end nodes of firebase, but I am not sure how to query correctly using Firebase /node.js

My database looks like this:

Database -> User (i.e. Greg, Mike, etc.) -> Randomly Generated String (i.e. XKJFJ34234KSDF) -> General Info (Age, Height)

I do not know the randomly generated string for a user so I do not know how to get the age for everyone.

A sample output looks like this

```
{ 'Greg': 
   { '-KQwvifPzq6g1JnRPYZn': 
      { Age: 188,
        Height: 6.1
       }
   }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten your data more, your key should not be greg but instead the generated one you posted. Greg itself should be a property of that user.

```
{
    User: {
        '-KQwvifPzq6g1JnRPYZn' : {
            Name : 'Greg',
            Age : 188,
            Height : 6.1
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

So that you can write queries like so:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('user').orderByChild('Age').startAt(180).endAt(190)
firebase.database().ref().child('user').orderByChild('Age').equalTo(188)
```